# How can I distinguish entities scanned in different locations in Spring?

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have a spring boot application, and using the annotation @EntityScan and @EnableJpaRepositories I'm scanning a library jar for some entities I need to add to my local database.

Problem is that I need a pragmatic way of distinguish them. Prefix or something that can flag those entities as entities from the jar.

I found how I can add custom prefixes using naming strategies. But if I use that it adds it on all the tables and not just the ones from the jar.

Comment: How about `@Table(name = "<custom name>")` on your own entities?

Comment: Well thats kind of the idea, but I'm trying to make this all dynamic and configurable from the application.yml. Like a prefix or anything that can clearly tell me this is from the jar or this is from my project. If I write a custom name or prefix for my  entities I increase the chances of making mistakes.

Comment: I was thinking alongside of prefixes, because I need to be able to make a clear distinction between these 2 groups in the database

Comment: You normally don't want to have dynamic table names. That only adds more options for mistakes. If you need to distinct between the groups, set the names via `@Table` and use the prefix there

Comment: I don't want the table names to be dynamic, that in it self seems like a nightmare or a really bad headache.  I'm just trying to add the prefix dynamically :D. But by extending SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy I don't really get anything to go by on

Comment: Dynamic prefix for the table name? Because that would be a dynamic table name after all. Or are you talking about a prefix for the columns?

Comment: no no, table names just. But ye I get what you mean